# Javascript code works in console but not HTML (Click Function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

```
document.getElementById('hello').click();
```

The above code works when inserted into the google chrome console - It displays the dropdown of 'hello' - What I'm trying to do is open up a dropdown when I click a whole table row, using the following code

```
<tr onclick="document.getElementById('hello').click();">
```

Here is the dropdown I'm trying to activate

```
<a href="#" id="hello" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn dropdown-toggle"><i class="icon-cog">
```

Infact I do see the button being clicked when I click the row, but the dropdown does not toggle. Whats the best way to toggle the dropdown (The dropdown works if I simply click it, I'm trying to toggle it using javascript)

Thanks!

Comment: use jQuery to attach an onclick handler for your table row. why are you using getElementById if you have jQuery included?

Comment: use jQuery `slideToggle()` instead of all this js stuff.

Comment: Please post all your codes (HTML/CSS) it is hard to figure out with the codes you have now

Answer (score 0):

Try like:

```
<tr onclick='$("#hello").trigger("click");'></tr>
```

Comment: I modified the code with single quote, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about scenario, but this is what I came up with. Please note that I have changed `tr` to `p` for the demo. Change it back to suit your needs.

```js
var helloID = document.getElementById("hello");

function initDropdown() {
    helloID.click();
}

helloID.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
    alert ("Click triggered on ID : " + evt.target.id);
});
```

```html
<p onclick="initDropdown();">Click Me</p>
<a href="#" id="hello" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn dropdown-toggle"></a>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>


        <tr onclick="$('#hello').click();">
```

Comment: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script> use this